References and suggestions for calculus-1 B.Tech
I have just cleared the entrance examination and am planning on doing Mathematics and computing (B.Tech). The semester has not yet started but I am planning to pre-initiate the studies to get a lead from the very start. I went through the curriculum for the course of the college I am planning to take admission in. Calculus is a major part of the 1st semester and my record with calculus has been good.
So, I want suggestions for where to start Calculus-1 and which YouTube channels websites or books would be great for the purpose.

First, you can try Gilbert Strang - Calculus. It is very good to start.
Next, you can try to read Tom Apostol - Calculus(Vol 1 and Vol 2). It is excellent, but you need to put in serious effort. I mean to learn better, try to solve as many exercises as possible from that book.
"The Only Way To Learn Mathematics Is To Do Mathematics" — Paul Halmos.
Lastly, you can try Michael Spivak. It’s a little harder than Apostol, but it's still one of the best books to learn Calculus.
You also asked for some YouTube channels: You can visit the following channels

Professor Leonard's YouTube channel

Claculus playlist of Michel van Biezen

NPTEL playlist on Calculus


I hope this will help you :-) Thanks!

Thanks man I would look into them

You are welcome!
